# Unable to access custom options section

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom-options, tabs, option

Using *mageworx advance product options* extension i have created option templates and associated to the products and saved.
in the magento 1.9.2.4

Now i came to product and clicked on '**custom options**' tab but not showing anything. but other tabs like 'categories', 'upsells'...etc can able to access and view.

Not getting any console log errors in the firebug.

please help me how can I overcome this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know this extension but you can try to find out what the problem is by checking your logs. For instance you could:

- check if there is a javascript error in your browser,
- check if there is any http request that failed,
- check your magento logs,
- check your php logs,

Since you mention that you got no javascript error in your console, try checking your logs in your magento docroot var/log/. For instance you could run tail -f to see the errors on the console:

```
tail -f /path/to/magento/var/log/*.log
```

Or additionally you can enable developer mode to see the errors on the browser. You can do this by defining the server parameter MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE on your vhost or simply by commenting lines 73 and 75 and uncommenting line 77 in your index.php

Change this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replaying @lloiacono. let me check and update you.

Comment: Thank you so much @lloiacono i have found and fixed the issue according to your steps.

Answer (score -2):

I have found and fixed the issue in the file **magento Root/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php**. (line number 375)

[Please click on reference link:](https://support.webcto.eu/index.php/Knowledgebase/Article/View/50/8/item-mage_catalog_model_product-with-the-same-id-already-exist)

Comment: You've fixed the symptom, not a cause. You should not edit core files, ever.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. so how to fix this ?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa One way to fix this issue is by adding a group_by on the specific ID field in the original query. I would suggest contacting mageworx support to let them know about the bug